# how to show lightbox popup with image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, html2canvas

In the following code. After save button clicked it is asking for download the output image generated from Html2canvas. How to chage this code so that instaed of asking to download it will generate the image on the fly with 'lightbox' feature.

I tried as :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>test2</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js?rev032"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#load').click(function() {
                    html2canvas($('#testdiv'), {
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                window.location.href = img;

                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="testdiv">
            <h1>Testing</h1>
            <h4>One column:</h4>
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="load"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the visitor to the image like you do here:

```
window.location.href = img;
```

You can add an invisible (`display: none`) image to the page:

```
 <img src="" id="image" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 30%; z-index: 1000;" />
```

And show it with your canvas image data like so:

```
$('#image').attr('src', img).fadeIn(200);
```

Now this won't create a very interesting lightbox without some additional work, but for that I would suggest you use a plugin instead. Something like [Slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) or [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

Comment: thanks Magnus. one thing can i put some border or make this #image like lightbox without those plugins. I don't want any fancy popup.

Comment: Sure. Here's some additional styling for the `<img>` you can use and fiddle around with `display: none; position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 20%; z-index: 1000; border: 10px solid #fff; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #444;`. Or try it here http://jsfiddle.net/8A4rw/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 $("#containerID").empty().append(canvas); // containerID is the container element for your rendered image
```

to append image on your page. And in the same way try giving canvas or img (in your case) as url to your lightbox code.

Comment: thanks rajesh.it just show the canvas img in the same page.not as a popup lightbox.

Comment: actually i am not used in lightbox code in my post. So, tried to figured it out how to inject this feature.